# c++ newbie, A program from Stroustrup`s book

Tags: c++, visual-c++

in chapter 4 there is a programm that i cant get how to make it working

My English is pretty poor, I apologize for it

Here is the task:

To make a programm, using 'while'. It must 'cin' 2 numbers and 'cout' them

In this chapter we were learning about vectors, so i decided to use them

here is my code:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    vector<int> numbers;
    int temp;
    cout << "Your numbers are:" << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    numbers.push_back(temp);
    while (i > numbers.size())
        cout << numbers[temp];


    keep_window_open();

}
```

Cheers!

credits to john,

here is the working code

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{

    vector<int> num;

    int temp;

    cout << "your numbers" << endl;

    while (cin>>temp)
    {
        num.push_back(temp);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); ++i)
    cout << num[i] << endl;



    keep_window_open();

}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What compiler do you have? Give us some information on how to solve your problem.

Comment: @lucas92 The problem is, i have Russian MS VS2010, but the warning number is C4018, so it is probably something like this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3050045 That's only a warning you could ignore it. If you want to fix it then replace `int i = 3;` with `size_t i = 3;`.

Comment: Try running the code under debugger. Watch values of variables while you step through the code. You might get a few insights. Because, frankly, that looks like you mashed code together which felt right, but without actually understanding what it does... Like, the `while` loop, you expect it to end when either `numbers.size()` or `i` change so that condition becomes untrue, but where are you changing either?

Comment: this one seems working, cheers to john, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot wrong with your code. The most obvious thing is that you only ask for one number but you said you must 'cin' two numbers.

Here's some code that inputs two numbers and puts them in a vector

```
int temp;
cin >> temp; // get first number
numbers.push_back(temp);
cin >> temp; // get second number
numbers.push_back(temp);
```

Your code to output the vector is wrong too. Here's some code to 'cout' a vector

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
```